# how to enable selected row in gridview in asp .net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" EnablePersistedSelection="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>            
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

here is code behind:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure3", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridViewRow gr = GridView1.SelectedRow;
                gr.Cells[1].Text = Textusername.Text;
                gr.Cells[2].Text = Textclass.Text;
                gr.Cells[3].Text = Textsection.Text;
                gr.Cells[4].Text = Textaddress.Text;

            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure1", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
```

The selected row did not select in gridview. May i know how to enable gridview row. I used msdn and other documents and i followed,but nothing helps.

I design i set enable selection, but still i didn't find out issue.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: you could save the selectedrowindex in a variable then used in `btnsub_Click` like `GridView1.Rows[index_varable].Cells[1].Text = Textusername.Text;`

Comment: Monitor `SelectedIndexChanged` and `SelectedIndexChanging` events for `SelectedRow` and `NewSelectedIndex`. Also check that you are NOT setting `SelectedRow` to Nothing/Null or `SelectedIndex` to -1 in any other locations. Also ensure that `Select` command of any row is clicked before accessing the `SelectedRow` in any event or better set default `SelectedIndex`. [system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @RojalinSahoo: can you please elaborated ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we get SelectedRow of GridView Upon some GridviewRow Action event like `OnSelectedIndexChanged` , `OnSelectedIndexChanging` , `OnRowEditing`  or from Template control like `Button` click. But here in your coding I don't think your `btnsub_Click` is inside Gridview so If you want to use the SelectedGridViewRow  after your  GridviewRow Action event then save the index in some temporary variable or pass the variable to method as argument.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    int index = Gridview1.SelectedIndex;
    hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
  }
```

**OR** In OnRowEditing also you can get the index of row

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int index = gr.RowIndex;
                hidval.Value = index.ToString();
            }
        }
```

and on button Click you can get the hiddenfield value as index:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure3", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenfield.Value))
                {
                int index = Convert.ToInt16(hiddenfield.Value);
                GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text = Textusername.Text;
                GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = Textclass.Text;
                GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text = Textsection.Text;
                GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text = Textaddress.Text;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure1", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: My question is, when i select row, it will selected, but when i edit row, it didn't selected..

Comment: when select-> edit->submit, it works fine,and selected row is works fine.. but edit->submit , it doesn't work..

Comment: If it's edit --> submit  then use only OnRowEditting code block there also I mentioned how to fetch the index of edited row.

Comment: ok . in that code protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Gridview1.SelectedIndex;
            hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
        } .. gridview1 doesn't exist in the current context..

Comment: Check that your ID of GridView is correct or not? May that it's GridView1 `protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) { int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex; hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString(); }`

Comment: ok. sorry, i ,made a mistake.. hiddenfield also doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: you have to add a hiddenfield in aspx page:`<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenfield" runat="server">` make sure your ID is same in aspx and codebehind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94158/discussion-between-rani-and-rojalin-sahoo).

Comment: i can cleary see that this answer is from years ago but maybe you can help me. i have problems in selecting a row. i mean i can not select a row at all even that i have the option AllowRowSelect="True"  in my grid